# Index Match Array: Index Range And Multiple Matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a block of data in the following layout on tab Group Commissions (I'm attaching a photo as well.). On a separate tab named for the agent Paul, I'm trying to cross reference the Client Name in cell B11 and the Agent name in cell B4 with the data on Group Commissions to return a specific agent's Commission %. So if on tab Paul I have "Client 1" in B11 and "Paul" in B4, I want to be able to return "12.5". Paul is not always in Agent 4. Any agent can be in Agent 2, Agent 3, or Agent 4 for a given Client.

[image]

I have this formula working, but it's not quite what I want, because I can't hard code the row numbers.

```
{=INDEX('Group Commissions'!G:I,MATCH('Paul'!B11,'Group Commissions'!A:A,0),MATCH(B4,'Group Commissions'!C143:E143,0))}
```

However, using a range of columns causes the formula to error out. As I mentioned, I cannot hard code for row numbers so now I'm stuck. Is this even possible?

```
{=INDEX('Group Commissions'!G:I,MATCH('Paul'!B11,'Group Commissions'!A:A,0),MATCH(B4,'Group Commissions'!C:E,0))}
```

Comment: bonus for *'photo'*.

Comment: If you were to add some more sample data to your *'photo'* (including the cells you mention in your question), and show what the end result would look like, it would be easier to understand what you're trying to do.  (Check out "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]".)  Also, I'm unsure what you're getting at about ***"hard-coding the rows numbers"*** but in case it helps, this `=Row()` will return the row number of the cell into which it's entered.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX('Group Commissions'!G1:I5,MATCH(Paul!B11,'Group Commissions'!A1:A5,0),SMALL(IF(Paul!B4=IF('Group Commissions'!A1:A5=Paul!B11,'Group Commissions'!C1:E5),IF('Group Commissions'!A1:A5=Paul!B11,COLUMN('Group Commissions'!C1:E5)-COLUMN(C:C)+1)),1))`

Okay, this is a bit messy but achieves what you are looking for.

For the second argument (column number) I have had to use a nested IF() statement to build an array of column numbers (offest to the start of the INDEX() clause, used column calculations for ease of reading only, I would normally subtract the number required).

I first produce an array of FALSE for all cells for rows that do match the client and the correct values for rows that do:

`IF('Group Commissions'!A1:A5=Paul!B11,'Group Commissions'!C1:E5)`

I then check this array for the agent name and equate that against the column numbers that I want returned (same formula but returning column number minus the index offset):

`IF(Paul!B4=[Previus part],IF('Group Commissions'!A1:A5=Paul!B11,COLUMN('Group Commissions'!C1:E5)-COLUMN(C:C)+1)`

This is wrapped in `SMALL()` so we can return the smallest result (putting numbers first) so we get the column number as the result.